# Representing colimits of morphisms

Tags: category-theory

For a functor $F : \mathcal{I} \to \mathcal{C}$, the limit $\varprojlim F$ and colimit $\varinjlim F$ represent the functors which map to a limit of sets
$$ Y \mapsto \varprojlim \operatorname{Mor}(Y,F(i)) \quad \text{and} \quad
Y \mapsto \varprojlim \operatorname{Mor}(F(i),Y)$$
according to [Stacks Remark 4.14.4](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/002H).

Is there also a name for objects in $\mathcal{C}$ which represent the functors which map to a colimit of sets
$$ Y \mapsto \varinjlim \operatorname{Mor}(Y,F(i)) \quad \text{and} \quad Y \mapsto \varinjlim \operatorname{Mor}(F(i),Y)?$$

Comment: Hint 1: representable functors are continuous.

Comment: Hint 2: Look at *examples* first.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg so do you mean by Hint 1 that if $\DeclareMathOperator{\Mor}{Mor}\Mor(Y,Z) \cong \varinjlim(Y,F(i))$ for some representing object $Z$ then by continuity we would have for another functor $G : \mathcal{I} \to \mathcal{C}$ that $\varprojlim \varinjlim \Mor(G(i'),F(i)) = \varprojlim \Mor(G(i'),Z) = \Mor(\varprojlim G,Z) = \varinjlim \Mor(\varprojlim G,F(i)) = \varinjlim \varprojlim \Mor(G(i'),F(i))$ and this is a contradiction because $\varprojlim \varinjlim \neq \varinjlim \varprojlim$ in general?